# Is there a way to switch on/off android internet access with ADB or command line?

Tags: android, adb

I need to disable/enable my android phone internet connection (to change its IP)

Is there a way to do it with command line or any tool so I can switch internet data (I notices any time I switch internet data, I got a new IP address)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `svc` command through adb to disable and then enable it with another command and you can add a sleep (like 2 seconds) in between. I'm not sure if `sleep` is required or not, but it sounds logical to me.

```
adb shell "svc data disable && sleep 2 && svc data enable"
```

Comment: In addition, if you need a tool (as you mentioned) you can use [ADB-Idea](https://github.com/pbreault/adb-idea) which provides 2 menus for enabling/disabling data. Also, you can fork it and add the command above as a new button

Answer (score 0):

In fact solution I found:

```
adb shell input keyevent 4 && adb shell am start -a android.settings.AIRPLANE_MODE_SETTINGS && adb shell input keyevent 20 && adb shell input keyevent 66
```

svc data enable/diabled disconnects data, but does not renew the IP address.